# React Testing Library: Testing boolean state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

I am currently writing a test using the testing-library/react package.

On the second click of my test, the text should not be in the document, but it is.

Here is the component I am testing:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { InfoType } from '../../constants'

type Props = {
    type: InfoType
}

const HelpWidget = ({ type }: Props) => {
    const [isHover, setHover] = useState<boolean>(false)

    return (
        <div className="help-widget">
            <img
                src={require('../../../public/images/info.svg')}
                onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
                onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}
                onClick={() => setHover(!isHover)}
            />
            {isHover ? <div className="info">{type}</div> : <div></div>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HelpWidget
```

Here is the test I wrote:

```
import React from 'react'
import { screen, render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'
import HelpWidget from '../components/helpWidget/helpWidget'


// Testing if the HelpWidget conditionally renders based on the isHover boolean state.
test('helpWidget conditionally renders to the page', () => {
    const epk4Post = 'Select a persona to post this'
    render(<HelpWidget type={epk4Post} />)
    const imageElement = screen.getByRole("img")
    userEvent.click(imageElement)
    screen.debug()
    expect(screen.getByText(/select a persona to post this/i)).toBeInTheDocument()
    userEvent.click(imageElement)
    screen.debug()
});
```

And here is what I get when I run screen.debug() to see the DOM output. Here you can clearly see that on the second click, the text is still within the document when it should ***not*** be:
[image]

Please share your thoughts! Thank you.

Comment: Are the mouse enter and mouse exit events firing too? That could cause your problem.

Comment: One guess is that maybe the click method in the test framework is triggering a mouse enter event, so isHover isn’t what you’d expect if only the click event happened.

Comment: Have you try to await waitFor(() => expect(...)) ? RTL should do it for you but it is worth a try

Comment: @bob the mouse enter and exit events are not firing but not sure how I would go about implementing that.

Comment: @FlorianMotteau Where is the async operation that waitFor is warranted?

Comment: I rearranged the test to use a waitFor on finding the text to NOT be in the document first which is expected to return true, then firing a click event on the img tag, and asserting the text to be in the document without a waitFor and that seems to be working. This is strange though because if I fire an event before the assertion of the text to NOT be there, it still returns true when it would return false. @FlorianMotteau

Comment: Strange indeed, but I assume that your problem is related to the component lifecycle. Note that theoretically we don't need to waitFor (if I understand correctly). You can also try findBy* queries, which return promises (https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#using-waitfor-to-wait-for-elements-that-can-be-queried-with-find, https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#findby-queries)

Comment: @FlorianMotteau Yes, that is also a wonderful article by Kent.